# Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-7

I am trying to upload images in ASW S3. But I get the error Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found. So I tried to run `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` But it gives me error . The error is :

```
 Problem 1
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.0.0, ..., 2.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^2.0.0 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.1, ..., 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 1.1.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.0.0-alpha.1, ..., 2.0.0-alpha.2] require league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.1 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.1] but the package is fixed to 1.1.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.0.0-alpha.4, ..., 2.0.0-beta.1] require league/flysystem 2.0.0-alpha.3 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0-alpha.3] but the package is fixed to 1.1.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.0.0-beta.2, ..., 2.0.0-beta.3] require league/flysystem ^2.0.0-beta.1 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0-beta.1, ..., 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 1.1.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 2.0.0-RC1 requires league/flysystem ^2.0.0-RC1 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0-RC1, 2.0.0, 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 1.1.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.0.0-alpha.1, ..., 2.x-dev].
```

My PHP version is : 7.4.11 and my Alaravel version is  7.30.0. Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try run this command in your terminal

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ^1.0
```

It works very well in my last experience using Laravel 7.30.3 (PHP v7.4)